# Row sample with limited combinations

Tags: r, dataframe, unique, sample

I am trying to get a sample from a large dataset of three columns.
The sample needs to meet the following criteria:

- Get a specific number of rows of every group value. There are three group values (1,2-3,4-5)
- Use only a specific number of characters in rows letter1 and letter2. That is to say: The condition regarding the limited number of letters is verified in this way: (where s is the solution dataframe)

  `NROW(unique(append(s$letter1,s$letter2)))
  4`

Minimal dataset looks like:

```
>df
letter1 letter2 value
a        b      1
a        c      1
a        d      3
b        a      1
c        b      1
c        d      2
c        e      4
d        a      5
d        e      1
d        c      2
```

(Value in lettter1 is always different from value in letter2).

For instance out of the example dataset I want a sample that includes 1 row of value 4-5, 1 row of value 2-3 and 4 rows of value 1. I want only combinations of 4 different letters to appear on the first two columns. In this case there are two possible solutions (and permutations of those), both using letters a,b,c,d. I just need to obtain one (or a permutation), I don't care which.

```
>s1
letter1 letter2 value       
a        b      1
a        c      1
a        d      3
b        a      1
c        b      1
d        a      5

>s2
letter1 letter2 value
a        b      1
a        c      1
b        a      1
c        b      1
c        d      2
d        a      5
```

**Solution for minimal dataframe but not real (larger) one**

I have solved the problem for the minimal dataframe above, but unfortunately is too slow for the real dataframe I need to process. This solutions consists on:

- Obtaining every possible combination of the desired number of unique letters (u = 4 in this example).
- For every one of those combinations, permutations in sets of two (the way they can appear in columns *letter1* and *letter2* in the dataframe).
- Get rows in the permutations dataframe (l) that are also in the original one (df), using semi_join().
- Get the rows belonging to each one the value groups and check if they are enough to meet the required number of rows for every group.
- If so, and if there are more than necessary to meet the requirement, choose randomly between them.

Function below returns the first group of u letters, with whose combination we can meet the required number of row in every group specified by groups. groups is a numeric vector of three elmements which represent the number of rows for every value group. groups[1] is the number of required rows with value 1, groups[2] the number of required rows with values 2-3 and groups[3] the number of required rows with values 4-5.

```
library(trotter)
library(gtools)
library(dplyr)

obtainValues <- function (df,u,groups){

# Get unique letter values in the dataframe
lett <- unique(append(df$letter1,df$letter2))

# All possible combinations of letters in lett in groups of u letters
letters <- cpv(u,lett)

# Iterate over any possible group of 4 letters
for(i in 1:length(letters)){

    l <- as.character(letters[i])
    l <- as.data.frame(permutations(u,2,l),stringAsFactors=FALSE)
    names(l) <- c("letter1","letter2")

    dc <- semi_join(df,l,by = c("letter1", "letter2"))


    #Groups of values of each type with the current letters
    g1 <- dc[dc$value == 1,]
    g2 <- dc[dc$value > 1 & dc$value < 4,]
    g3 <- dc[dc$value > 3,] 

    if(NROW(g1) >= groups[1] & NROW(g2) >= groups[2] & NROW(g3) >= groups[2]){

        # I do not want more rows of each type than the requested ones
        g1 <- g1[sample(nrow(g1),groups[1]),] 
        g2 <- g2[sample(nrow(g2),groups[2]),]
        g3 <- g3[sample(nrow(g3),groups[3]),]

        # Join chosen rows in a dataframe
        g <- rbind(g1,g2)
        g <- rbind(g,g3)
        return(g)
    }
 }
}


df <- data.frame(c("a","a","a","b","c","c","c","d","d","d"),c("b","c","d","a","b","d","e","a","e","c"), c(1,1,3,1,1,2,4,5,1,2), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
names(df) <- c("letter1","letter2","value")

groups <- c(4,1,1)
u <- 4
obtainValues(df,u,tieGroups)
```

**Problem**

The real dataframe is too large and it is not possible to iterate over 1:length(letters). It is possible to split the length and do a for loop for different group of values in letters at a time but it is really slow as my dataframe is quite large. Is there any other solution? Any way to avoid the for loop? Or a way to somehow adapt my solution to larger dataframes?

Comment: There may only be 2 possibiliies with respect to the value 1 group  (I'll take your word for that)but there are 3 with value 2 and 2 with value 3 so there are (at least) 12 possible results.

Comment: @42- Sorry, but I don't get your point. Using just combinations of 4 different letters in the first two columns I can't see more than 2 solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I would first do a randomization of the row-orders, then a first `split` on the values column (since you know the size of the draws within that grouping), and then pick the first 4 items conditional on `!duplicated( paste( letter1, letter2, sep="_"))`

```
rdf1 <- df1[ sample(nrow(df1)) , ] 
vspl <- with( rdf1, split(rdf1, findInterval(0,1.5,3.5, 5.5) )  )
#--------
> vspl
$`1`
   letter1 letter2 value
3        a       d     3
6        c       d     2
7        c       e     4
5        c       b     1
2        a       c     1
1        a       b     1
10       d       c     2
4        b       a     1
8        d       a     5
9        d       e     1
#--------
 vspl <- with( rdf1, split(rdf1, findInterval(rdf1$value, c(0,1.5,3.5, 5.5) ) ))
do.call( rbind, 
   lapply( names(vspl),   # names rather than values to later determine number of rows
     function(x) vspl[[x]][  # work on the nth item in the list
       !duplicated( paste(vspl[[ x]]$letter1,vspl[[x]]$letter2,sep="_")), ][ # drop dupes
            1:(if (x=="1") 4 else 1), ,drop=FALSE])  ) # select correct number
  letter1 letter2 value
5       c       b     1
2       a       c     1
1       a       b     1
4       b       a     1
3       a       d     3
7       c       e     4
```

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear enough in my question about the requirement of using only combinations of 4 different letters in the first two columns. Your solution does not meet this requirement as the dataframe provided includes 5 different letters (a,b,c,d,e). I have updated my answer, I hope it is more clear now.